# limit the view depending on the values - Laravel - Spatie

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-9

I need, depending on the role/permission of each user, to limit the database records that are displayed in the view index.

For example, I need a certain user to only be able to see the records with the "pendiente" value in the "estado" column.

code of my controller index function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $siniestros = Siniestro::paginate(50);

          //return DB::select('select localidad from siniestros'); //---> Devuelve los datos de la columna estados
    
        
        return view('siniestros.index', compact('siniestros'));

        $now = Carbon::now();
    }
```

code of my index.blade view

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
 



    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-header">
            <h3 class="page__heading">Siniestros</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                
            
                        @can('crear-siniestro')
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('siniestros.create') }}">Nuevo</a>
                        @endcan
            
                        <table class="table table-sm m-1 p-1 table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablita" style="width:100%">
                                <thead style="background-color:hsl(213, 99%, 49%)">                                     
                                    <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Siniestro</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Coordinador</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Actualizado</th>                                    
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Patente</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Cliente</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Fecha ingreso</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Fecha gestión</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Captura de pantalla</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Estado</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Modalidad</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Observaciones</th>
                                    @can('derivar-siniestro')
                                    <!-- <th style="color:#fff;">Screenshot</th> -->
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Dirección</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Localidad</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Inspector</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Motivo</th>
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Enviar Orden</th>
                                    @endcan
                                    <th style="color:#fff;">Acciones</th>                                                                   
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                            @foreach ($siniestros as $siniestro)
                            <tr>
                                <td style="display: none;">{{ $siniestro->id }}</td>                                
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->siniestro }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->creator->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->editor->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->patente }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->cliente }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->created_at }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->updated_at }}</td>
                                <td><img alt="img" src="/img/{{ $siniestro->imagen }}" width="100px"></td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->estado }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->modalidad }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->observaciones }}</td>
                                @can('derivar-siniestro')
                                <!-- <td><a href="{{ $siniestro->url }}" target="blank_" >Ver documento</a></td> -->
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->direccion }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->localidad }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->inspector }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->motivo }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $siniestro->enviarorden }}</td>
                                @endcan
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{ route('siniestros.destroy',$siniestro->id) }}" method="POST">                                        
                                        @can('editar-siniestro')
                                        <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" href="{{ route('siniestros.edit',$siniestro->id) }}">Editar</a>
                                        @endcan
                                        
                                        
                                      
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        @can('borrar-siniestro')
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Borrar</button>
                                        @endcan

                                    </form>
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <!-- Paginacion a la derecha -->
                        <div class="pagination justify-content-end">
                            {!! $siniestros->links() !!}
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
   

    
@endsection

@section('javas')

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablita').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,

        
    });
})
</script>
<!-- DataTables JS -->

<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.11.5/b-2.2.2/b-colvis-2.2.2/b-html5-2.2.2/b-print-2.2.2/r-2.2.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            const languages = {
                'es': 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json'
            };

            $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.Buttons.defaults.dom.button, {
                className: 'btn btn-sm'
            })
            $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                responsive: true,
                language: {
                    url: languages['es']
                },
                pageLength: 25,
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                buttons: [{
                        extend: 'copy',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'Copiar',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csv',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'CSV',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'Excel',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdf',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'PDF',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'Imprimir',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        className: 'btn-light',
                        text: 'Visibilidad Columnas',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

Attached screenshot of my index.blade view

[index.blade view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2fMQ.png)

Of course I can filter with my DataTable, but the idea is that for security reasons, each user can only view the records according to their "estado"/value

I thank you in advance, and tell me if it is relevant that I attach other information

[I need to do this, but in the backend, with the roles/permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09kHj.png)

Model Siniestro.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Wildside\Userstamps\Userstamps;



class Siniestro extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Userstamps;
   
    protected $fillable = ['created_by', 'imagen', 'updated_by', 'deleted_by', 'siniestro', 'patente', 'cliente', 'fechaip', 'estado', 'modalidad',
    'observaciones', 'fechacierre', 'compania', 'contacto', 'codigoinspeccion', 'inspector', 'direccion', 'localidad', 'telefono', 'motivo', 'link', 'enviarorden', 'email'];


   public function archivos()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Archivo::class);
   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, I am writing this controller for you:

Please don't forget to add on top of your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $siniestros = Siniestro::paginate(50);

    if ($user->hasDirectPermission('crear-siniestro')) {
        $siniestros->makeHidden(['estado']);
    }
    
    return view('siniestros.index', compact('siniestros'));

    $now = Carbon::now();
}
```

This should work if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thanks for comment. In this way that you indicate, I only limit that the person with said status can or cannot see the column. I would need that with the "derivar-siniestros" permissions I can only see the records with "pending" status. That is, I need to restrict in terms of the value of the field/column, not in terms of the field/column itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, can you please rephrase what you need?

Comment: I just added another image to the post, check. I need, as seen in the image, to be able to filter the records that are displayed, depending on who is logged in. For example that users 1 and 2 can see only those with the value "pendiente" in the "estado" column, as shown. But let it be a limitation in the backend

Comment: I don't think you can limit the front-end in the backend unless you create a different view for the users. Of course, you can exclude those variables in the backend, but in the front-end the table will remain as it is, but that part of the table will be empty.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the update. Let me check.

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui Can you please share the model? I will need it to write the function in the controller.

Comment: is that I don't need to constrain the column... the column must be seen; I need to restrict that each user can see records depending on the value of the "estado" columne. There are many employees, and each one deals with different tasks. Then each employee must be able to see only the records that are in the "status" that corresponds to them. I already uploaded the view of the model

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui Sorry for the delay, there, I edited my answer. Check if it works for you. It should hide `Estado` in case the user has the permission of `crear-siniestro`

Comment: Daniel L, this throws me the error Undefined variable $user.. 
that would make the status column invisible anyway. I need to stop seeing the entries, depending on the value of "estado"

Comment: Edited @Sr.Miyagui please check.

Comment: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user"

Comment: @Sr.Miyagui just made another edit, please try.